# Gradle with Visual Studio gives empty project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, gradle

I'm currently working on a "simple" Xamarin project.
In this project i wanted to add "Service Cloud Snap-ins for Mobile Apps" for both Android and iOS. For now i'm focussing on Android.
( https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/service_snap-ins_mobile_apps/units/service_snap-ins_mobile_apps_android )

Here they explain that when working natively with Android Studio that you use something called Gradle to get third party code.

Fortunately i was able to find a Gradle for Visual Studio ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarinGradleBindings ).

1. Set dependency id & repositories to look from

[image]

2. Select jar/aar

[image]

3. Binding_Servicesdk was successfully created and build. And a reference to Binding_Servicesdk is added for the Android project.

[image]

4. But inside the Android project i still can't use anything from the newly created wrapper class.

[image]

5. I looked at the wrapper project with Telerik's JustDecompile and saw that it only contains a BuildConfig class. Notting else.

[image]

Looks like this would explain why the wrapper project isn't helping me. It isn't formed properly.
But what am i missing here. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: This plugin simply downloads the .aar and creates a binding project for you. It does not fix any of the [common problems](https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#2-fixing-issues) binding projects have.

Comment: It doesn't give me any build errors. If i do this with other, larger, projects it does give me build errors. So for the moment i'm assuming there aren't any build or binding issues.

Comment: In my common problems section I linked above, there is a item regarding "Library References" in which you won't necessarily always get an error if a reference is missing. The generator will just silently fail to generate the full library if a reference is missing.